# In VSCode, how do we get preview of an elements over tooltip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm new into programming world and currently following some tutorials over the Internet.
Long story short, here's the problem I'd encountered.

[1. When I hover over my code, a minimalized tooltip is shown as below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA6EG.png)

[2. In the tutorial, when the lecturer hover over the same code, it shows the actual value instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1bjn.png)

Is there any ways to customize the tooltip shown to me every time when I hover over something? I've tried holding down ALT key but it doesn't work.

I was coding along with the tutorial, so there shouldn't be any difference between my code and the tutorial's code. I just found it useful if I can see the values every time when I hover over them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the following extension in vscode: Visual Studio IntelliCode

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'd installed the IntelliCode plugin and it's not helping still...

Comment: Ensure it is enable editor.hover.enabled in settings

If it keeps failing:
Disable all extensions.
Test it in a simple example like:
```
let test ={a:3}
//then hover over test
```

If you are using import ES Modules you need to ensure you have node --version >=14. And ensure you have   "type": "module" included in package.json

Comment: @MrrEluu Did you follow the instructions? If it was helpful and solved the problem can you mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Hey pal, sorry for the late reply.  I didn't follow the instructions yet, I held down CTRL key when I hover over the object, it worked in a different way,  but not exactly as shown in the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Is this using node.js? If so you might have forgotten to import something. If you are 100% sure you did everything right, there might be some VSCODE plugin that he has installed.

It would also be helpful if you gave us a link to the video so we know what this is about.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Yes I'm using node.js, the Express framework. I'm following the video from the beginning to the end, I hope I didn't miss anything, but it's worth a check. 

It's a Web Developer Bootcamp by Colt Steele over Udemy, I'm afraid that I can't give you the link to the video directly as it's a paid content.